# How to solve gulp image copy issue on build?

Tags: image, gulp

**Problem** - copied images end up with size `0 x 0 px`.

In my `gulpfile.js` I copy images from the `app` directory to the `dist` directory, which works well. Here's a simplified version of the task:

```
gulp.task('html-deploy', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'app/img/**/*',
        'app/**/*.html'
        ],
        {
            base: 'app'
        }
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
/app
    index.html
    /img
        image1.png
        image2.png
```

Everything copies over well and nice, however the images don't display in the browser, even though filepaths are correct.

The weird thing is when I locate the images directly in Finder (osx) I can't view them there either, although the filesizes and read/write values are correct too.

This is probably because the copied images end up being 0x0 px in size. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Was facing the same issue with ionic 2 application.
I included gulp task

```
gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/images/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www/build/images'));
});
```

called it from other build tasks are called (gulp task build)

and changed my image reference to refer from build folder:

```
 <img src="build/images/mylogo.png" height="50px" width="50px">
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of an answer to my own question - at least it fixed the problem.

Instead of directly copying the images I copy them via [`gulp-imagemin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin), and voilà!

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin')
var del = require('del')

// Minify and copy new images to dist
    gulp.task('imagemin', ['clean'], function() {
        return gulp.src('app/img/**/*')
            .pipe(changed('dist/img'))
            .pipe(imagemin())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'))
    })
```